# Why the pointer is losing its value in this Go program

Tags: go

I don't understand why the pointer `s` is `nil` even after the `input()` method initialised it. Any idea?

```
package main

import "fmt"


type ps string

func(s *ps)input(){
    x := ps("a")
    s = &x
}
func(s *ps)output(){

}

func main() {
    var v *ps
    v.input()
    if v == nil{
        fmt.Println("v shouldn't be nil")
    }
}
```

Playground http://play.golang.org/p/jU2hoMP7TS

Comment: You need `*s = x`: the `*` operator on `s` means "dereference `s`", or informally "get what `s` points to", so you can read `*s = x` (somewhat awkwardly) as "set what `s` points to to be `x`."

Comment: @twotwotwo, got it! so the real issue here is that I've got used too much with structs pointers which handle the reference/deference automatically by the dot notation, right?

Comment: Yep, exactly--all hidden from you if you're just calling methods on the variable or looking up attributes and not using other operators.

Comment: still if I try to defer the pointer ( `*s = x` ) I get a panic error as it's not yet initialised. I'm wondering how am I supposed to fix it.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that--you do need a space for a `ps` allocated in memory to copy `x` into (even if it's empty), so in `main` you'd have to do `v := new(ps)` or similar in place of `var v *ps`.

Comment: Relevant is http://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types `The value of an uninitialized pointer is nil. `

Comment: @Momer   The question was why the pointer was still nil after I assigned x value ( see the `input()` method)

Comment: (answer-ified for posterity)

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat My link was directly related to the fact that your `var v *ps` was not initialized, such that it was nil; this resulted in your panic. By using `v := new(ps)` or `var v *ps; v = new(ps)`, it will be initialized.

Comment: @Momer  The question was not why the pointer was nil. The question was why the pointer was nil even after (supposedly) I assigned it a value.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat And thus, the answer is that it was not initialized when the method was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things--`main` needs to allocate space for a `ps` that `input` can write into, which you can do by replacing `var v *ps` with `v := new(ps)`. The string will be `""`, but it doesn't matter what it is, just that there's space set aside in memory for a [string header](http://research.swtch.com/godata) that `input` can write to. As Momer said, [otherwise the pointer's `nil`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) and your program panics trying to dereference it.

And in order to assign through a pointer, `input` needs to use `*s = x`. Since `*s` is, informally, "get what `s` points to", you can read that as "change what `s` points to to `x`". Usually the automatic ref/deref behavior around the dot operator and method calls saves you from that, but when you assign through a pointer type or do other operations (arithmetic, indexing, etc.) the dereference needs to be there in the code.

Answer (score 0):

v value (0) is passed into v.input. Passed value is stored in a local variable s. s value is modified. No one is saving new s value back into v.

If you want something modified in your function, you must pass pointer to the value. (or reference for slices, maps and so on).

If you want to change pointer value, you should pass pointer to your pointer.

Alex

Comment: Asker is passing a pointer (`func input(s *ps)`)--just wasn't using the necessary code to assign to the memory it points to rather than change the pointer itself.